# Running rails application inside a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Is it possible to running embedded rails application inside a Ruby gem? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see how the `rails plugin new --full --mountable` command's output contains the `test/dummy`  Rails application.

This command will actually generate a gem structure for a Rails engine.

Comment: Loool. Thank you very much. Rails's an awesome framework. :)))))))